# stat file not getting updated in CQ5

Tags: caching, aem

The stat file in my cache root is not getting updated with activation requests; therefore old pages are getting served from dispatcher. The time-stamp is not getting modified. I read a post somewhere that the osgi configuration  jcr observation listener might be stuck; and restarting it might cause the stat file's timestamp to update. If anybody knows how can we restart that particular osgi bundle; it will help a lot

Comment: Are the connection parameters for the flush agent correct? In the CQ admin panel, go to the page showing the replication agents and select your dispatcher flush agent. There you have a link to test the connection from the publisher to the dispatcher.

Answer (score 0):

The stat file is updated when a new page or resource is activated to the publish instance. When you perform a request through the dispatcher, it will talk to the publisher only if the modification date of the stat file is newer than the modification date of the requested file in the dispatcher cache. So in my opinion this problem is not related to your publish instance, but to your dispatcher. Install the latest dispatcher module for your http server and see if the problem still persists.

> The /statfile property identifies the file to use as the statfile. Dispatcher uses this file to register the time of the most recent content update. The statfile can be any file on the web server.
>
> The statfile has no content. When content is updated, Dispatcher updates the timestamp. The default statfile is named .stat and is stored in the docroot. Dispatcher blocks access to the statfile.

See https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/dispatcher/disp-config.html#par_title_28 for more.

Edit: If you still want to restart the bundle related to the replication, try restarting the com.day.cq.cq-replication bundle

Comment: The dispatcher won't talk to the dispatcher right away. If auto-invalidation is configured, it will compare the modification time of the requested file against that of the corresponding stat file. Only if the stat file is newer than the requested file will the dispatcher connect to the publisher and fetch an updated version.

Comment: Sure, you are absolutely correct. I wrote very quickly my answer and didn't read exactly what I wrote. The dispatcher will talk to the publisher only if the modification date of the stat file is newer than the modification date of the requested file in the dispatcher cache. I'll  correct my answer